# IWA doesn't work with WSO2 Identity-Server(wso2is-km-5.9.0)

Tags: wso2, kerberos, kdc, wso2-identity-server

I have setup IWA for my service provider by following these documents:
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/configuring-iwa-on-linux/
https://medium.com/@farasath/integrated-windows-authentication-with-kerberos-and-wso2-identity-server-ffcd8263a0f1

However upon submitting the login request, I get HTTP 500 error.
Why am I facing this issue?
Note: The same IWA configuration work fine for older version i.e WSO2 Identity-
Server(wso2is-km-5.7.0)

[image: IWA error]

Comment: Can you confirm whether you have followed the steps in https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/configuring-iwa-on-linux/?

The configuration model has changed from IS 5.7.0 to IS 5.9.0 a bit.

Comment: Yes, I have followed the same steps mentioned there

Comment: Anyone facing the same issue with this version of WSO2??..Please guide us

Comment: Is it just me who is facing this issue with the latest version...or did anyone resolve it???

Comment: Can you explain your setup (Client machine, AD and IS are located) and how the flow happens in your environment?

Comment: Here AD is our Kerberos server, and every user already has a Kerberos ticket in his/her system as they have to use AD credentials each day when logging into their system.Also we have configured AD as our Primary Data store using a LDAP connection. So client,AD and IS are there in the same realm.

Comment: Are each lf these AD, client and IS and application server (where the app your are trying to login) in separate machines or VMs?

Comment: Yes, AD,client and app server are all in separate VMs

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to the reason explained in https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/8028

There is a check in the code to make sure the IWA login request does not come from the same host as the IS. Due to a bug in the tomcat version used in IS 5.9.0, this check fails even if the IWA login is initiated from a different host than IS.

Comment: Thank you @farasath